# MySQL Replace function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display all the people who name Jason, and replace Jason to Jill.

However, I tried the following SQL statement is not working

```
SELECT * FROM DigitalTV WHERE REPLACE('Jason', 'ason', 'ill');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the column you want to replace names is called `NAME`, you can use a query like:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  REPLACE(NAME, 'ason', 'ill') As CHANGED_NAME
FROM DigitalTV 
WHERE NAME='Jason';`
```

This will bring an extra column with the name `CHANGED_NAME`. If you do not want it, use each and every column name in the selector but `NAME`. It should be modified as `REPLACE(NAME, 'ason', 'ill')`

Comment: Since we know `NAME='Jason'`, you could `SELECT 'Jill' AS CHANGED_NAME`. (No `REPLACE` necessary).

Comment: I currently have two columns, first_name, last_name. I want to make sure I can replace 'Jason' to 'Jill' in both columns